# Not all Docker Images are showing on GitHub container registry

Tags: docker, github, ghcr, github-container-registry

I can not see docker images on the GitHub container repository ([https://github.com/orgs/{OWNER}/packages](https://github.com/orgs/%7BOWNER%7D/packages)) for non-existing repositories.

I am talking about [GitHub container registry](https://docs.github.com/en/packages/working-with-a-github-packages-registry/working-with-the-container-registry)

#### How to reproduce

If you create repository `repository-A` on GitHub and then push docker image `docker push ghcr.io/OWNER/repository-A:latest`. I can then go to project packages (on GitHub web app) and see that image as a container package or whatever.

But If you push the docker image and set its name to something that is different from any repository name you have e.g. (`docker push ghcr.io/OWNER/unknown-repo:latest`) you will not be able to see that image anywhere on GitHub web app. You will be able to pull this image and push again with a different tag, but on let's call it `package explorer` on web app you will not be able to see it e.g. ([https://github.com/orgs/{OWNER}/packages](https://github.com/orgs/%7BOWNER%7D/packages)).

Am I only having this problem and how to solve it? Thanks

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Comment: @JohnC. Unfortunately, not.

Comment: I think I may have solved it. At least in my case. I am a member of an org and an owner of the org had to do this: 1) go to the project page, 2) on the right-hand side click on "packages", 3) set the permissions on who could "read" packages.

Comment: @JohnC.

I added your comment as an answer but the moderator for some reason delete it.